# karma plugin dependencies not being found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, karma-runner

When I run `karma start` I get the following issues

```
C:\devl\JS\myProject>karma start
06 09 2015 11:30:19.133:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-chrome-launcher
".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev
06 09 2015 11:30:19.149:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-firefox-launche
r".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev
06 09 2015 11:30:19.159:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-ie-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-ie-launcher --save-dev
```

when I do `npm list` I can see the dependencies at the bottom of the tree

```
├─┬ karma-chrome-launcher@0.2.0
│ ├─┬ fs-access@1.0.0
│ │ └── null-check@1.0.0
│ └─┬ which@1.1.1
│   └─┬ is-absolute@0.1.7
│     └── is-relative@0.1.3
├── karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.6
├─┬ karma-ie-launcher@0.2.0
│ └── lodash@3.10.1
└── karma-jasmine@0.3.6
```

I have tried nuking my node_dependencies and running `npm install` again and i'm not sure what else to try

EDIT: I have verified in my node_dependencies directory and the plugin directories are in there.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There are a two seemingly-similar complaints when first getting started with [Karma](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma):

```
[preprocess]: Can not load "webpack", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

and

```
[plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-webpack".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-webpack --save-dev
```

The following is my best recommendation for fixing these two problems with your configuration…

#### "Can not load "XYZ", it is not registered!" (sic)

The typical solution to the 'Perhaps you are missing some plugin?' message is to make sure it's included within the `plugins` array in `karma.conf.js`.

```
plugins: [
  'karma-chrome-launcher',
  'karma-tap',
  'karma-sourcemap-loader',
  'karma-webpack' // *** This 'registers' the Karma webpack plugin.
],
```

#### "Cannot find plugin 'karma-xyz'."

If you've already installed it by running `npm install karma-xyz --save-dev`, but Karma still prompts (read: taunts) you with the "Did you forget to install it ?" warning, you may have a global installation of the Karma module.

Chances are that when you installed a global copy of the `karma-cli` using `-g`, you included `karma` (or were told to do so by a well-meaning tutorial), but that can cause problems resolving modules in certain versions (i.e., every version I've ever used). [Karma's installation documentation](https://karma-runner.github.io/latest/intro/installation.html) recommends that the module should be a local installation using `npm install karma --save-dev`.

If you have a global Karma installation, try something like:

```
$ npm uninstall -g karma
$ npm install karma --save-dev
```

Comment: This is the complete answer.  It should be accepted.

Comment: Worked for me. Additional note: the package "karma-cli" should be installed globally. Otherwise, the karma start command does not work on windows. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800933/running-karma-after-installation-results-in-karma-is-not-recognized-as-an-inte

Answer (score 22):

I think that you installed these plugins globally.

I had the same problem and I solved by installing the chrome-karma-launcher using the [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link) flag:

```
 npm install karma-chrome-launcher --save-dev --link
```

Do this with all browsers' plugins

```
 npm install karma-firefox-launcher --save-dev --link
 npm install karma-ie-launcher --save-dev --link
```

I don't know if this is the best approach, but this solved for me.

Answer (score 7):

My answer might be a very rookie one, but did you add those plugins in the plugins array in the karma config file?

For example:

```
    plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
        'karma-spec-reporter',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-coverage',
        'karma-phantomjs-launcher'
    ],
```

Mine got resolved after I added the plugins to this array.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem, but i fixed by this command :

```
npm install -g karma-cli
```

Comment: This also solved it for me. I mistakenly installed "karma" globally instead of "karma-cli" which broke all kinds of things.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add if someone come acrosss!!

I was getting an annoying issue, "Cannot load browser "Chrome": it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?" when I run 'grunt test'

I had added the plugin in plugins[] in karma.conf.js, but still I was getting this error . The issue was I didn't add the plugin into karma:options:plugins array in GruntFile.js.After I added the plugin there, the issue vanished!!