# Cannot find plugin "karma-mocha-reporter". npm install works, but error persist.

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, npm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

As soon as I try to add

```
    plugins: [
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-mocha-reporter'
    ],
```

to my karma.config.js

I get this error:

```
C:\git\angularjs\.bin>karma start karma.config.js
11 11 2015 15:21:10.617:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-mocha-reporter".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev
11 11 2015 15:21:10.671:INFO [karma]: Karma v0.13.14 server started at http://localhost:9876/
11 11 2015 15:21:10.672:WARN [launcher]: Can not load "Chrome", it is not registered!
  Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
```

obviously I tried running the

*npm install karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev*

also globally installing it

*npm install karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev -g*

and it installs fine. But still I keep getting the error messages when I launch karma. Is it installing in the wrong location or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the karma-chrome-launcher plugin in the plugins array:

```
plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine',
  'karma-mocha-reporter',
  'karma-chrome-launcher'
],
```

How I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425580/karma-plugin-dependencies-not-being-found/33907633#33907633), I think that you installed the karma-mocha-reporter plugin globally.

Try to install karma-mocha-reporter using the link flag:

```
npm install karma-mocha-reporter --save-dev --link
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you also want *karma-chrome-launcher*

Try

```
npm install --save-dev karma-chrome-launcher
```

Comment: Thanks, but karma-chrome-launcher is already installed too.. :/