# Angular-cli Karma tests not working on new project

Tags: angular

Noticed Karma tests not running on a new angular-cli project

1. ng new MyProject
2. Let project build
3. npm run test
4. The following is output, and a blank browser is opened to (localhost:9876/?id=50029001). The page is identified as 'Untitled'.

   10% building modules 1/1 modules 0 active06 11 2017 13:15:08.477:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://lo
   calhost:9876/
   06 11 2017 13:15:08.493:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
   06 11 2017 13:15:08.493:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser Chrome with unlimited concurrency
   06 11 2017 13:15:08.493:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome         06 11 2017 13:15:22.195:WARN [karma]: No c
   aptured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
   06 11 2017 13:16:08.507:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
   06 11 2017 13:16:08.601:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (1/2).
   06 11 2017 13:17:08.618:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
   06 11 2017 13:17:08.758:INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again (2/2).
   06 11 2017 13:18:08.774:WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
   06 11 2017 13:18:08.960:ERROR [launcher]: Chrome failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.

Is this a new break with the release of Angular-5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the same directory as  karma.conf.js and run the command  "karma start"

Comment: Running 'karma start' provides the following response:

karma : The term 'karma' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ karma start
+ ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (karma:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: install it : npm install -g karma-cli

Comment: A search on the karma error found this link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800933/running-karma-after-installation-results-in-karma-is-not-recognized-as-an-inte)

The fix is to run  'npm install karma-cli'

Answer (score 1):

Although you write that you did a new project, so npm install is done with no node_modules folder existing before, I want to share my solution in case someone gets to this thread like I did. I had the same problem and tried a lot of the suggested solutions I found, but what finally solved it for me was to delete the node_modules folder and getting everything new via npm install.

same issue: [Karma - Chrome failed 2 times (cannot start). Giving up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31966434/karma-chrome-failed-2-times-cannot-start-giving-up/49296461#49296461)